# Missing fi's for if statements

Tags: shell-script

I've written a script where I've got some nested-if statements.

```
if [ choice = "1" ]; then
        if [ $package == *".tar.gz" ]; then //Could not find fi for this if
        tar -zxvf folder.tar.gz
        if [ $package == *".tar.bz2" ]; then
        tar -xvfj folder.tar.bz2
./configure
make 
make install
elif [ choice = "2" ]; then
dpkg -i package.deb
fi 
//Expected fi
```

Have written where I get the fi errors in the script.

Comment: This script has a lot of mistakes. I recommend you to read a basic [guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) or  [an introduction](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic structure for conditions is the following:

```bash
if [ condition ]; then
    dosomething
fi
```

With else:

```bash
if [ condition ]; then
    dosomething
elif [ condition ]; then
    dootherthing
else
    thelastchancetodosomething
fi
```

Also, I think this condition in your code is wrong:

```bash
if [ $package == *".tar.gz" ]; then
    tar -zxvf folder.tar.gz
fi
```

If I'm understanding it correctly, it should be something like:

```
if echo $package | grep -qF ".tar.gz"; then
    tar -zxvf $package
fi
```

Oh, and use `#` for comments instead of `//`.

Fixing your example and improving the indentation to be more clear:

```
if [ choice = "1" ]; then
    if echo $package | grep -qF ".tar.gz"; then
        tar -zxvf $package
    # You need to close previous `if` with a `fi` you want to use another
    # `if` here below, but we can use `elif`, so we don't need to close it.
    elif echo $package | grep -qF ".tar.bz2"; then
        tar -xvfj $package
    fi
    cd ${package%.*.*} # this removes the .tar.* extension
    ./configure
    make 
    make install
elif [ choice = "2" ]; then
    dpkg -i $package
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a typical case where you'd want to use `case`:

```
case $choice in
  (1)
     case $package in
       (*.tar.gz) tar -zxvf folder.tar.gz;;
       (*.tar.bz2) tar -jxvf folder.tar.bz2;;
     esac &&
       ./configure &&
       make &&
       make install
     ;;
  (2)
     dpkg -i package.deb
     ;;
esac
```